# Executing stored procedure with Entity Framework (EF) returning all records, even though I applied paging, sorting, filtering

Tags: database, entity-framework, procedure

Executing stored procedure with Entity Framework (EF) returning all records, even though I applied paging, sorting, filtering.

Below is the code.

```
var result = base.Context.proc_App_Contracts_All(Customer_No).AsQueryable()
                .Where(filterExpression == null ? e => e.Contract_Number == e.Contract_Number : filterExpression)
                .OrderBy(sortExpression)
                .Skip((request.Page - 1) * request.PageSize)
                .Take(request.PageSize)
                .ToList());
```

I think the reason is EF filtering records on application level (in case of stored procedure) not on database level, that's why EF fetches all the records to the application and then apply the sorting and filtering etc.

So here I wants to know that is there any way to execute stored procedure in same way just like we query to a table or view in EF which eventually makes a query wrapper around your query or Should I convert my stored procedure into a sql view.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Stored procedure does not reurn **IQueryable**  write your  proc app_Contracts_All pls, and how did you have configured in your DbContext

Answer (score 0):

Refer the following article for doing server side pagination for different version of SQL Server. The SQL Server 2012 OFFSET FETCH clause is the best in terms of performance. Again it depending upon the version you are using. You can add additional SP parameters and modify the query to do the server side filtering as well.

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2696/comparing-performance-for-different-sql-server-paging-methods/

MSDN Link on OFFSET FETCH Clause:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg699618(v=sql.110).aspx

Hope this answer your question.